# Auto Award bounty to already auto awarded answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, bounty

I already got auto awarded for an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29832277/730807).

The questioner wanted more information so he commented and declared another bounty.

I replied my answer as comment to that question and not edited my answer.

My auto awarded answer was not accepted as answer.

There are no answers for the questions other than mine.

My answer has score of three as of now.

So I've got just curious, Am I going to be auto awarded for the answer again ?

Comment: If I recall correctly, answers that were already present before the bounty started are not eligible for automatic awards.

Comment: Automatic bounty awards are only ever applied to posts created **after** the bounty was started.

Comment: ok is it possible that he can manually award the answer to already auto awarded answer (It is obvious that it is not posted during the latest bounty) ?

Comment: Yes, I see no restriction on manually awarding bounties to any answer, no matter when it was posted. The restriction on the answer needing to be posted after the bounty was started only applies to auto awarding. Source: http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty.

Comment: I got my confusions clear.Anybody could post it as answer.I'll accept it.